# Eclipse RCP: Right aligned search field in toolbar

Tags: eclipse-rcp, toolbar

I would like to have a right aligned search field in the toolbar of an Eclipse RCP application. I already created the text field as ControlContribution and the respective search action in the ActionBarAdvisor class:

```
protected void fillCoolBar(ICoolBarManager coolBar) {
  IToolBarManager toolbar = new ToolBarManager(SWT.FLAT | SWT.RIGHT);
  //...
  toolbar.add(new ControlContribution("searchText") {
  //...
```

This works and I have the search field in the toolbar. But how can I align the search text (or the toolbar with the search text) on the right side?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 9):

If you mean positioning search toolbar on the right hand site of the main toolbar, then consider using these areas instead (when using [org.eclipse.ui.menus](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_cmd_menus.htm) extension point):

```
toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar - the top-level tool bar 
toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.trim.command1 - the top left trim 
toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.trim.command2 - the top right trim 
toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.trim.vertical1 - the left vertical trim 
toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.trim.vertical2 - the right vertical trim 
toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.trim.status - the status line trim
```

Comment: Hey Michael, could you make an example? Is it compatible with e4 ?

Comment: @Campa Hi. Sorry, is been 8 years since I've submitted the answer - I don't even have the environment to write an example, since I've switched to a different tech stack since then..